# Use Compile to speed up evaluation

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, version-7

I have read, that using `Compile` command can speed up evaluations in mathematica. I have a mathematical expression, which I evaluate using following command:

```
n = 5000
k = 10
c = n/k
a = Floor[n* Log[2]]
b = a + 1
pk1 = Table[
   Sum[Binomial[a, i]*StirlingS2[i, r]*(n - c)^(-i), {i, r, a}], {r, 
    1, c - 1}];
```

I was trying to use `Compile` to evaluate this, but I don't know how to 'tell' Compile that I want to evaluate for range `{r,1,c-1}`, I just made:

```
cf = Compile[{?}, 
  Sum[Binomial[a, i]*StirlingS2[i, r]*(n - c)^(-i), {i, r, a}]]
```

Can someone suggest how I should transmor my comment to `compile` commend? Or how I can speed up my evaluations in different way?

Comment: You need to look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions - you'll see that `Binomial` and `StirlingS2` cannot be compiled, so you are unlikely to benefit from compilation.

Comment: `ParallelTable` may speed up a bit. As well as putting `n=5000.` and not `n=5000`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [blochwave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13162/blochwave), your code can't benefit from compilation. To speed up your code, take [Rolf Mertig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29/rolf-mertig)'s advise may be the best. Making use of the `Listable` attribute of those arithmetical function will also help a little:

```
(* Tested under n = 1000, dual-core laptop *)
pk1 = Table[
    Sum[Binomial[a, i]*StirlingS2[i, r]*(n - c)^(-i), {i, r, a}], {r, 1, c - 1}]; //
AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {44.5980000, Null}
> ```

```
pk2 = ParallelTable[
    Sum[Binomial[a, i]*StirlingS2[i, r]*(n - c)^(-i), {i, r, a}], {r, 1, c - 1}]; //
AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {22.5580000, Null}
> ```

```
pk3 = ParallelTable[
    With[{i = Range[r, a]}, 
        Total[Binomial[a, i] StirlingS2[i, r] (n - c)^(-i)]], {r, c - 1}]; // 
AbsoluteTiming

pk1 == pk2 == pk3
```

> ```
> {17.4624000, Null}
> True
> ```